# Flutter google play says app was signed in debug mode

Tags: android, flutter, google-play, release

I'm trying to release a Flutter app on google play. 
I've created keystore following this guide https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android#signing-the-app

Now I'm trying to build my release app with this command

```
flutter build apk --release --split-per-abi
```

(I've even added --release flag to make it explicit)
And after that I get 2 apk files:

```
app-arm64-v8a-release.apk
```

and

```
app-armeabi-v7a-release.apk
```

Even their names clearely say they are both release files. 
Then I try to upload any of them to google play and I always get this error message:

> Download failed
>
> The downloaded APK file or Android App Bundle was signed in debug
>   mode. Sign the file or set in release mode. Learn more about
>   signatures.

My gradle.build file contains this:

```
signingConfigs {
    release {
        keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
        keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
        storeFile file(keystoreProperties['storeFile'])
        storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
    }
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
}
```

And there are no problems when I build it.

What am I missing here?
I'm completely stuck with that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this. The reason was that I had used flutter run --release command before. So gradle had cached debug keystore and actually used it to sign a release apk.

**The solution is simple**

Open a new terminal in your project directory and type:

```
cd android
```

When you're in android directory of your project, type this command

```
./gradlew clean
```

Pay special attention to ./ If you simply type gradlew clean it will not work, even though gradlew is indeed inside "android" directory

After gradle cache is cleaned, simply run build command again

```
flutter build apk --split-per-abi
```

And you'll get correctly signed release apks that wil be accepted by *Google Play*

Comment: have the same problem. Tried your solution with flutter build appbundle. Then checking with keytool -list -printcert -jarfile app-release.aab gives following: Owner: C=US, O=Android, CN=Android Debug

Comment: it turned out I just forgot to change signingConfig signingConfigs.debug line to signingConfig signingConfigs.release inside buildTypes { release {...}}